# How to check if a certain value is present in any firestore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here's my code:

```js
var bJoin = document.getElementById('bJoin');
var joincode = document.getElementById('joincodeipt');
bJoin.addEventListener('click', function(){
    db.collection('arrayslist').where('id','==',joincode).get().then(snapshot => {
        if(snapshot.exists){
            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {

            })
        } else {
            console.log('false')
        }

    })
})
```

Essentially I want to check if `joincode` exists anywhere in `arrayslist`.
The `joincode` is the same as the `id`.

On both occassions (valid or invalid code), this outputs:

```
Uncaught FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data.
Unsupported field value: a custom HTMLInputElement object
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you can't pass an `HTMLInputElement` to `where()`.  Firestore doesn't know how to reach into that element and get the value that the user entered.  What you can do instead is reach into it yourself to get its string value and pass that along.  If you want to get the string value out of the element, you can use its `value` property.

```
db.collection('arrayslist').where('id','==',joincode.value)
```

Comment: It sounds like you now have a new problem that's different than the one you started with.  Please ask a new question that explains the specific query you're doing (with no variables, just hard-coded strings), and the specific data in the database that should match.  We should be able to see how the query matches the data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `joincode` is a `HTMLInputElement` and you cannot compare a id with an html element.

You can fix this by using the `value` of the input element by using:

```js
joincode.value
```

Comment: thanks, but now it still prints `false` with a valid code.